# How to access computed properties

Tags: ember.js

I have a Ember.Object like:

```
App.HelpVideoInfo = Ember.Object.extend({
MyAccount: ['FAe8w0cUCJ0', 'How-to: Change "My Account"'],
StoreInformation: ['UddOjEG-hXw', 'How-to: Change Store Information'],

getSecondAccount:function()
{
    return this.get('MyAccount')[1];
} .property('MyAccount'),
});
```

I want to binding from my Ember.View to getSecondAccount (computed property). I used:

```
App.IconMeaningDialogView = Ember.View.extend({
       accountBinding:    'App.HelpVideoInfo.getSecondAccount';
  });
```

But it doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naming conventions are not conform with those from Ember, see [Emberist blog post](http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html).

You should name classes `UpperCase`, instances and properties `lowerCase`. Then the binding works as expected, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/PQYYH/.

I would also recommend to use the built in array accessor `objectAt`.

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{#view App.IconMeaningDialogView}}
        {{account}}
    {{/view}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.helpVideoInfo = Ember.Object.create({
    myAccount: ['FAe8w0cUCJ0', 'How-to: Change "My Account"'],
    storeInformation: ['UddOjEG-hXw', 'How-to: Change Store Information'],

    secondAccount: function() {
        return this.get('myAccount').objectAt(1);
    }.property('myAccount').cacheable()
});

App.IconMeaningDialogView = Ember.View.extend({
    accountBinding: 'App.helpVideoInfo.secondAccount'
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to access that property would be as follows

```
App.IconMeaningDialogView = Ember.View.extend({
    accountBinding: Ember.Binding.from('App.HelpVideoInfo.getSecondAccount')
});
```

Refer to [Advanced Emberjs Bidnings](http://code418.com/blog/2012/03/26/advanced-emberjs-bindings/)

Comment: There is no difference between using `Ember.Binding.from('App.HelpVideoInfo.getSecondAccount')` and specifying it via `accountBinding: 'App.HelpVideoInfo.getSecondAccount'`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to *extend* an *Ember.Object* to create your class `App.HelpVideoInfo`. Instead, if you *create* a new object there, it would allow you to bind to the properties in the way you want.

However, if you would like to use the `App.HelpVideoInfo` subclass, then you would have to *create* an object before you can bind to its properties. An example of how you can do it this: http://jsfiddle.net/74KX7/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, musically_ut. But I just able to choose the best answer.